# variable scope with if else statements in php

Tags: php

I have the following code. I am trying to handle two form posts with in the same page. What the code is doing is whenever a user clicks "next14days" button, it display the data for the next 14 days and If the user clicks "prev14days" it should display the data of the previouse 14 days. This for me is not working.

for example lets say current date is 2011/01/03 and I hit next14days the current date should be 2011/01/17. This works but when I hit prev14days which should take me back to 2011/01/03, it is going to 2010/12/20 which looks like (2011/01/03 - 14).

the page refreshes every time a user hits one of the buttons and anything inside the IF clause is not accessible either way.

```
<?php

if(($prevFlag == '' || $nextFlag == ''))
{   
    $currentDay = date('Y/m/d');
    $SQL4 = "Exec EmployeeVac '" . $currentDay . "'";
    $result4 = mssql_query($SQL4,$link1) or die('An error occured: ' . mssql_get_last_message());

}

if (isset($_POST['next14submit'])) 
{

    $nextFlag = 'yes';

    if($prevFlag == 'yes')
    {
        $next14 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($prev14 . "+14 days"));
        $currentDay = $next14;
        $SQL4 = "Exec EmployeeVac '" . $currentDay . "'";
        $result4 = mssql_query($SQL4,$link1) or die('An error occured: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
    }
    else
    {
        $next14 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($currentDay . "+14 days"));
        $currentDay = $next14;
        $SQL4 = "Exec EmployeeVac '" . $currentDay . "'";
        $result4 = mssql_query($SQL4,$link1) or die('An error occured: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
    }
} 

if (isset($_POST['prev14submit'])) 
{
    $prevFlag = 'yes';
    echo $nextFlag;
    if($nextFlag == 'yes')
    {
        $prev14 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($next14 . "-14 days"));
        $currentDay = $prev14;
        $SQL4 = "Exec EmployeeVac '" . $currentDay . "'";
        $result4 = mssql_query($SQL4,$link1) or die('An error occured: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
    }
    else
    {
        $prev14 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($currentDay . "-14 days"));
        $currentDay = $prev14;
        $SQL4 = "Exec EmployeeVac '" . $currentDay . "'";
        $result4 = mssql_query($SQL4,$link1) or die('An error occured: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not passing any reference for the 'previous 14 days' to be calculated from...

Essentially, in your script you are caclulating the previous 14 days from todays date..

kinda lost as to this section.. (unless this is not all the code)

```
if(($prevFlag == '' || $nextFlag == '')) {        $currentDay = date('Y/m/d');
```

essentially, that code will always exicute...

then later you are referencing:

```
$prev14 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($currentDay . "-14 days"));
```

so you are just subtracting 14 days from today?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include what the current date was in your form, so that your php script knows what date to start with in going forward or back.

```
if(isset($_POST['currentDay'])){
    $currentDay = strtotime($_POST['currentDay']);
} else {
    $currentDay = date('Y/m/d');
}
```

You have to reallize that php is not a stateful language.  Your script only knows what you pass it.  If you don't pass it a starting date, then it won't know where to start in adding or removing 14 days.

Good luck.